# Unable to map regular expression for pattern matching

Tags: regex, command-line, findstr

I want to search a pattern such that there is an occurence of more than one "AND" within a parenthesis for eg .

> ((158 - 9900) AND 25261 AND ERC572P85-1)

So we have two ANDS here .
I have tried with the following regular expression

```
findstr /r /c:"^[(][^(]*[AND]*[AND]$[)])"
```

but didnt help

Comment: What characters can be between the "AND's"??

Comment: A good reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: I suppose is mandatory that before and after "AND's" must be a space, isn't it? If not, you could accept (ANDAND) for example.

Comment: yes there is a space between AND

Answer (score 0):

That won't match the example string, because the pattern searches for beginning of line, then a parenthesis, then any number of parentheses before the AND; but the string begins with two parentheses.